# Error while trying to compress a 10 sec video on react-native

Tags: android, react-native, ffmpeg

I am currently using the library [react-native-video-processing](https://github.com/shahen94/react-native-video-processing) to compress a 10 sec video on android. But this is the error I get while trying to compress it.

Any ideas suggestions?

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): Error: compress error:
>   failed. ffmpeg version 3.3.5 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg
>   developers  built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)  configuration: --target-os=linux
>   --cross-prefix=/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
>   --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot
>   --enable-libx264 --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-nonfree --disable-network --enable-gpl --enable-ffmpeg --enable-small --disable-filters --enable-filter=copy --enable-filter=trim --enable-filter=crop --enable-filter=scale --enable-filter=format --pkg-config=/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-3.3-pkg-config --prefix=/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include
>   -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-cxxflags= --extra-libs='-lx264 -lm'  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100  libavfilter     6. 82.100 / 
>   6. 82.100  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from
>   'file:///storage/emulated/0/Movies/VID_20171110_195700.mp4': 
>   Metadata:    major_brand     : mp42    minor_version   : 0
>   compatible_brands: isommp42    creation_time   :
>   2017-11-10T16:57:05.000000Z    com.android.version: 7.1.1  Duration:
>   00:00:03.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2094 kb/s    Stream #0:0(eng):
>   Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m), 720x480,
>   1991 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
>   (default)    Metadata:      rotate          : 270      creation_time
>   : 2017-11-10T16:57:05.000000Z      handler_name    : VideoHandle
>   Side data:      displaymatrix: rotation of 90.00 degrees    Stream
>
> ## 0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 95 kb/s (default)    Metadata:      creation_time   :
>
> 2017-11-10T16:57:05.000000Z      handler_name    : SoundHandleStream
>   mapping:  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264)) 
>   Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))Press [q] to stop,
>   [?] for helpError reinitializing filters!Failed to inject frame into
>   filter network: Out of memoryError while processing the decoded data
>   for stream #0:0[aac @ 0xf6f04c00] Qavg: 12036.106[aac @ 0xf6f04c00] 2
>   frames left in the queue on closingConversion failed! Error: compress
>   error: failed. ffmpeg version 3.3.5 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg
>   developers  built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)  configuration: --target-os=linux
>   --cross-prefix=/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
>   --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot
>   --enable-libx264 --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-nonfree --disable-network --enable-gpl --enable-ffmpeg --enable-small --disable-filters --enable-filter=copy --enable-filter=trim --enable-filter=crop --enable-filter=scale --enable-filter=format --pkg-config=/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-3.3-pkg-config --prefix=/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include
>   -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-cxxflags= --extra-libs='-lx264 -lm'  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100  libavfilter     6. 82.100 / 
>   6. 82.100  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from
>   'file:///storage/emulated/0/Movies/VID_20171110_195700.mp4': 
>   Metadata:    major_brand     : mp42    minor_version   : 0
>   compatible_brands: isommp42    creation_time   :
>   2017-11-10T16:57:05.000000Z    com.android.version: 7.1.1  Duration:
>   00:00:03.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2094 kb/s    Stream #0:0(eng):
>   Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m), 720x480,
>   1991 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
>   (default)    Metadata:      rotate          : 270      creation_time
>   : 2017-11-10T16:57:05.000000Z      handler_name    : VideoHandle
>   Side data:      displaymatrix: rotation of 90.00 degrees    Stream
>
> ## 0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 95 kb/s (default)    Metadata:      creation_time   :
>
> 2017-11-10T16:57:05.000000Z      handler_name    : SoundHandleStream
>   mapping:  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264)) 
>   Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))Press [q] to stop,
>   [?] for helpError reinitializing filters!Failed to inject frame into
>   filter network: Out of memoryError while processing the decoded data
>   for stream #0:0[aac @ 0xf6f04c00] Qavg: 12036.106[aac @ 0xf6f04c00] 2
>   frames left in the queue on closingConversion failed!
>       at createErrorFromErrorData (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:1807:15)
>       at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:1760:25
>       at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2118:16)
>       at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:1935:16
>       at MessageQueue.__guard (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2053:9)
>       at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:1934:12)
>       at http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.js:72:58

Comment: Looks like you ran out of memory on the system.